# Mysql queries not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

When i shifted my working code from local to my dedicated host, none of the query is working, however I am able to connect to the database. I know it should be something trivial but i am unable to work it out since last hour.

Here is my  code:

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(0);
$DbCon =  mysql_connect('localhost:1023','username','password');
mysql_select_db('dbname', $DbCon);
if (!$DbCon)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
echo("wait...\n");
    echo("Caching name...\n");
$query0="SELECT * FROM sometablename2";
$Result0 = mysql_query($query0,$DbCon);
$anarray=array();
    $anotherarray=array();
while($records0 = mysql_fetch_array($Result0))
{
        do something
}

}
```

The Output i get is : 
wait...
Caching name...
PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/to/php/file/code.php on line 42
PHP Warning:  mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/to/php/file/code.php on line 56

So, it's clear that I am able to connect to database but no output from this query. I have run the same query in the database and it is working. 
Any directions will be very helpful.

Comment: is something returned from this query?

Comment: that's the error, I am trying to select the whole table but nothing is returned from this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [mysql_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) function to find out what's wrong.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nonexistenttable", $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";
```

Edit: as per comment below, also try, for example:

```
// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: that's a great tip. thanks. It says database not selected when i check using this. Perplexing as I can see the database and can run queries too..Also it does not die with mysql_error().. Investigating more, will update here when i find anything..

Comment: You should also update your code to check if mysql_select_db worked correctly, e.g.

`// make foo the current db

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);

if (!$db_selected) {

    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());

}`